# Marging all JS and CSS into inline?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Assume a website that collects all required css and js file links into an array before including them in a header like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='[CSS-FILE-LINK].css' type='text/css' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='[JS-FILE-LINK].js'></script>
```

Some of those are local files and some are remote.

**In general**- is there any downside to include the links for the remote ones, but output the local ones inline?

**More specifically:** My main concern at this moment I guess is with conflicting variable names... CSS I guess just cascades in a way that is meant from the ground up to deal with conflicts/overriding... but JS I'm not sure- does a global variable in one js file conflict with a global variable in another?

**Bonus points:**
Assuming it is a good idea to do this to gain speed due to decreased latency between requests, would it be better to readfile() or file_get_contents() in this case?

Comment: I'm against remotely hosted CSS-files, unless you've hosted them yourself. If you don't host it on your own server, someone could change a small thing, completely breaking your page. But I'm guessing you have thought of that? ;)

Comment: All JavaScript files are executed in the exact same environment. There's only one global, which is `window`. Including everything inside the same HTML helps reduce the number of HTTP Requests, but to be honest the difference is minuscule.

Comment: If you have conflicting names in your javascript files you can "contain" them within a function like: (function(){ /*Your javascript here*/ })() but you should try to avoid inlining both javascript and CSS, as the answer posted while im writing this, your initial pageload might be faster, but once you have loaded the js and css files {nearly} every browser will cache them for you which will make subsequent pages load faster (the inlined js and css will have to be transmitted to browser on every request, eg not cacheable)

Comment: Hmmm good point... will js minifiers like yuicompressor take care of this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

well you could output the CSS from local files (please don't copypaste it, you're definitely in for trouble if you do :D).

What people usually do is that they keep the things linked in development and use concatenation and uglification as soon as it comes to production.

Global JS variables are generally a bad idea and yes, they can conflict (they are attached to the window object, which is globally available).

Answer (score 0):

The downside is your initial page load will be heavier. If your files are small it's still be a net gain in performance because of the reduced amount of requests.

CSS handles conflicts like you said, JS does not. That is why you [should not put things](http://conceptf1.blogspot.se/2014/02/why-to-avoid-global-variables-and-objects-in-javascript.html) [in the global scope](https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478).

Answer (score 0):

The JS global variables can make your web works badly, very badly. If you have the change I suggest you to use JS Module pattern so you can have separately namespaces so you don't have the problem with global JS.

If you want to win speed you can use amazon for store static content. You can just cache the request to your css/js files and it will be much faster, is not really hard con set up and is not expensive.